# Property not working in different OS, function throws an exception(System.Management.ManagementException: Not Found)

Tags: c#, exception, wmi

My code runs well in windows 10. But in windows 7 it reaches catch block when I try to get the list of usb devices connected using  List in the following code

```
public static IList<ManagementBaseObject> GetUsbDevices()
{
 List<ManagementBaseObject> usbDevices = new List<ManagementBaseObject> 

  ManagementObjectCollection curMoc = QueryMi("Select *from 
  Win32_PnPEntity");

  foreach (ManagementBaseObject device in curMoc)
    {
      ''''
      ''''
    }
    return ''''
 }


  private void checkDevice()
  {
  try
  {
   WriteLogError("CheckDevice");
   IList <ManagementBaseObject> usbDevices = USBHandler.GetUsbDevices();
    WriteLogError("got list");
    ''''
  }
   catch
   {
     WriteLogError("Exception");
   }
  }
```

"so after 'CheckDevice' I get 'Exception' in the log file."

Comment: Have you checked what the exception is?

Comment: If you use   catch (Exception e) instead of only catch. You can do WriteLogError(e). This way you can read what the Exception is

Comment: thanks I will try doing that

Comment: this is the exception:    System.Management.ManagementException: Not found 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.PropertyDataCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)

Comment: Please edit your question and add this valuable information there, not in a comment.

Comment: But i still did not find the solution why it thows

Comment: @HepsibaSolomon what is QueryMi? Which operating system are you using?

Comment: a query against Windows Management Infrastructure (MI) and return the resulting collection

Comment: public static ManagementObjectCollection QueryMi(string query)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
            ManagementObjectCollection result = managementObjectSearcher.Get();

            managementObjectSearcher.Dispose();
            return result;
        }

Comment: @styx I am using both windows 10 and 7, it works fine with windows 10 and throws exception with windows 7

Comment: Looks like your exception is being generated in code you didn't provide in your question.  Please edit your question and include any code related to getting properties.